# Multi-dimensional include

Tags: android, pointers, multidimensional-array, parse-platform, include

I need help with Parse queries. I have three classes which have pointers in this relation. Activity class with column "video" pointing to Video class which has another column "videoOwner" pointing to the _User class. What I want to achieve is to query the Activity class for a video and get the associated owner's details from the _User class. I have tried this

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> activityQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Activity");
    activityQuery.setLimit(1000);
    activityQuery.whereEqualTo("video", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Video", objectID));
    activityQuery.whereEqualTo("type", "comment");
    activityQuery.whereExists("video");
    activityQuery.include("video");
    activityQuery.include("video.videoOwner");
    activityQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> vList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) { 

                for (int i = 0; i != vList.size(); i++) {
                    commenterUsername = vList.get(i).getParseObject("video.videoOwner").getString("username");
                    commenterName = vList.get(i).getParseObject("video").getParseObject("videoOwner").getString("fullName");
                    Log.e("User", commenterUsername);
                }
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    });
```

but it clashes at the Log because commenterUsername is null. Any help to enable me to make this query is highly appreciated as i don't want to be making too many queries if there's a simple and cleaner solution available. Thanks

Comment: `vList.get(i).getParseObject("video").getParseObject("videoOwner").getString("username");` should work?

Comment: I assume it should but it is not working. Clashing at the Log is returning NPE so I guess noting is returned from the query.

Comment: In the code you posted you have `getParseObject("video.videoOwner")` which is invalid, whereas the code I posted in the first comment should be valid. So `getParseObject("video.videoOwner")`  should be `getParseObject("video").getParseObject("videoOwner")`

Comment: @cYrixmorten, you are right. Please post it as answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted you have `getParseObject("video.videoOwner")` which is invalid.

`getParseObject("video.videoOwner")` should be `getParseObject("video").getParseObject("videoOwner")`

The dot notation only works for include statements, so you have to get the individual objects like this.